# Disqus and WooCommerce review compatibility issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, integration, woocommerce, disqus

I am trying to use Woocommerce plugin and Disqus plugin together on my WordPress blog.

As I can see from other posts on internet, lot of users such as me are facing the issue that - Disqus disables reviews on product page created by Woocommerce.

As Disqus disables WordPress comments which in turn are used by Woocommerce for product review - now there is no way (as far as I could know) to show review form on Woocommerce.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

I have already tried the following:

1. Open Disqus plugin directly.
2. Go to line number 150 in disqus.php
3. notice the conditions which says for which posts types Disqus should not render comments.
4. add - if ( is_product() ) { return false; }

This will stop showing Disqus comment box from product pages created by Woocommerce and it will show usual review form. However, on submitting this - you will receive an error saying WP comments have been disabled.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was if I used Disqus plugin, it replaced my WordPress comment system with Disqus. Thus, disabling reviews on Woocommerce pages.

So instead using Disqus plugin, I simply used its universal code and added to my single.php file, before `<?php comments_template(); ?>` to be precise.

This seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by adding this code to my functions.php file:

```
add_action('the_post', 'sb_remove_woocommerce_disqus', 10, 2 );
remove_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'dsq_pre_comment_on_post');

function sb_remove_woocommerce_disqus( $post, $query ) {
global $post, $wp_query;

if ($query->is_main_query() && $post->post_type == 'product') { 
    remove_filter('comments_template', 'dsq_comments_template');
}
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as @darshak-parmar 's solution of adding the snippet to the theme file `single.php` might be overwritten when the theme is updated